# How to highlight a div when a fullcalendar event is dragged to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I am working with the [Smart Admin Theme](https://bootstraphunter.com/smartadmin-product.php) and I have installed a trash icon in the Theme's calender.

CSS:

```
.fc-view
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="well well-sm" id="deleteEventsDiv">
    <legend>
        Delete Events
    </legend>
    <img src="/img/avatars/cal-trash.png">
    <div class="note">
        <strong>Note:</strong> Drag and drop events here to delete them
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript (eventDragStop method from fullcalendar itself):

```
eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view, removeEvents ) {
    // This condition makes it easier to test if the event is over the trash can using Jquery
    if($('div#deleteEventsDiv').is(':hover')){
        // Confirmation popup
        $.SmartMessageBox({
            title : "Delete Event?",
            content : 'Are you sure you want to remove this event from the calender?',
            buttons : '[No][Yes]'
        }, function(ButtonPressed) {
            if (ButtonPressed === "Yes") {

                // You can change the URL and other details to your liking.
                // On success a small box notification will fire
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/events/' + event.id,
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    success: function(request) {
                        $.smallBox({
                            title : "Deleting Event",
                            content : "Event Deleted",
                            color : "#659265",
                            iconSmall : "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                            timeout : 4000
                        });
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
},
```

This is working fine. When a user hovers over the trash can div on the event of drag stop, a confirmation popup comes up and the ajax call is fired on 'Yes'.

Now I want to highlight the div when the mouse is over with the event. So I used the `eventDragStart` method like so:

```
eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
    $('div#deleteEventsDiv').mouseover(function(e){
        $(this).css({'background-color': '#A90329'});

        $('div#deleteEventsDiv').mouseout(function(){
            $(this).css({'background-color': 'white'});
        });
    });
},
```

But whenever I hover the event on the div it turns red for just a fraction of a second before it turns back white. Why is this happening? And how do I correct this?

If I remove the `mouseout` callback, it turns red fine. What is the way around this?

Comment: better use CSS 
     
     <style>
          div#deleteEventsDiv {'background-color': 'white'}
          div#deleteEventsDiv:hover {'background-color': 'red'}
     </style>

Comment: You are binding the `mousout` handler when you are in the `mouseover` handler **while dragging**. I think you want to bind those events after the calendar has rendered or what @Mr.A says, just solve it with CSS.

Comment: Not working using CSS. It is working fine when I hover the mouse but not when I am dragging the event along. What is the way around that?